# Are there any other half-fiends except for Draegloths that were created intentionally by a mortal race?

Tags: monsters, lore, forgotten-realms, dnd-3e

According to the Forgotten Realms wiki article on [Draegloths](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Draegloth#Society), they are **perhaps** the only variety of half-fiend that was created regularly and intentionally by a mortal race. (*Monster Compendium: Monsters of Faerûn*, p. 59)

Are there any other half-fiends except for Draegloths that were created intentionally by a mortal race?

Comment: In addition to the system and edition, can you tell us if you are looking for a lore based answer, or for a creature with relevant game statistics? What content is acceptable as a source?

Comment: I am not an expert on FR, but to me this seems like a straightforward lore question. System edition should not be an issue, right?

Comment: @Szega is completely correct, there is no especial need for a system tag here unless Spartakus specifically *wants* to limit things to the material from a particular edition. That said, it might be worthwhile—4e messed with FR lore a *lot*, and while 5e rolled back *most* of that (confirming how messed up 4e got), it still has some of it that doesn’t mesh with the larger body of material before 4e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your interpretation of "regularly and deliberately", there is at least one race that qualifies:

## Fey'ri

Races of Faerun

> The result of four noble houses of sun elves breeding with demons in an attempt to strengthen their bloodline, fey’ri are a type of planetouched that breeds true among their own kind. Marked by their fiendish blood, fey’ri are unique among most planetouched
>   in that they have a self-sustaining community, so they are raised among their own kind.

In addition, there are several races that are the result of interbreeding (Maeluth, Wispling, Alu-fiend, Cambion, etc.), however there is no direct evidence that these were deliberate and regular on the part of the mortal, rather than the fiend.